# Docker: cron within container no errors but still not working

Tags: linux, docker, cron, dockerfile

I am new to docker.  Managed to create a script which gets info from online source and populates an SQL DB.  All works well within docker container.

However, I need to make this to run for example every minute.

So I amended my working Dockerfile and added the following:

Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get install -y cron
COPY cronms /etc/cron.d/cronms
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cronms
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cronms
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
    
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log

#CMD [ "python3", "./my_script.py" ]  -- command before cron
```

my cronms file:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /my_script.py
```

Image builds without errors however when running it data is not being downloaded.

What I am missing please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your complete `Dockerfile`? What you've posted here is missing the `FROM` line, so it's hard to try to reproduce the behavior you've described.

Answer (score 1):

Your crontab file has incorrect syntax. From the [`cron` man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/crontab.5.html):

> The system crontab (`/etc/crontab`) and the packages crontabs (`/etc/cron.d/*`) use the same format, except that the username for the command is specified after the time and date fields and before the command.

So your `cronms` file should look like:

```
*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/python3 /my_script.py
```

I assume the `Dockerfile` in your question is truncated, but it's worth noting that for this to work you may need to explicitly install `python3` as well as `cron`, depending on which base image you're using.

---

If I build an image using this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y cron python3
COPY cronms /etc/cron.d/cronms
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cronms
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cronms
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

COPY my_script.py /my_script.py

CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

And this `cronms`:

```
*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/python3 /my_script.py
```

And this `my_script.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time

with open("/tmp/datafile", "a") as fd:
    fd.write(time.ctime())
    fd.write("\n")
```

Then I can confirm that everything works as expected: the script is
executed once a minute.

Note that *nothing* is written to `/var/log/cron.log`, however,
because `cron` logs to syslog, not to a file. To see output from
`cron`, you would need to arrange to run a syslog daemon, or use a
different cron daemon (for example, the busybox `crond` command can
log to a file or stderr).

Comment: Hi larks. Thanks for pointing that out but still it is not working. Yes, Dockerfile is truncated and I have all the installs included. Infact image works fine without the corn (using CMD [ "python3", "./my_script.py" ]). I am just editing it to make it run every 1 minute.  Are my cron lines in Dockerfile correct please?

Comment: Thanks a lot larsks. I used the chmod lines from above and all works. I must have had something missing.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I am using a linux environment and had to remove the `root` from the `cronms` file to get it to run properly.